# linking the text file with its database name in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How do i link a text file, uploaded in the uploads folder with its database name? I am uploading a file in the uploads folder using input method & saving its original file name in the database field as `file_url`

```
<table class="blog">
<?php
    foreach ($file as $Eachfile){
        $Eachfile['Data']['file_url'];
         echo "<a href='".$this->webroot."uploads/data/".$Eachfile['Data']['file_url']."' > 'Link' </a>";
    }
?>
```

> here at the 'Link' i need to show the original name which i get when i
>   am uploading the file using input method & storing the original file
>   name in the table field 'file_url

kindly help me 
thanks in advance.

Comment: So, are you asking how to insert a file path and file name into a database?

Comment: no i have already done that part... what i am asking is how to make a link to download the uploaded text file using its database file name which is stored using input method while uploading the file.

Comment: If the file is in a public web directory and you know the path name to it, just echo our a file path into a link's href, which basically looks like what you are trying to do.  It is not clear where you are having a problem.

Comment: try to change `$this->webroot` for `APP_DIR` constant
check the version of your cake, in 1.3 is `APP_DIR` in 2.0 is `APP_DIR` I don't know of other versions